# difference in syntax of python class creation - class name_class: class name_class(): and class name_class(Object):

Tags: python, python-3.x, class, oop

I am learning OOP with Python and I consider that I have already understood the basics to understand how to create and instantiate a class but I have a question of syntax. Reviewing different examples to practice I have been able to see that a class can be created with slight differences but that I instantiate them in the same way (without problems).

```
# Form 1
class Dog:

    def __init__(self, name):
        self.name = name

    def ladrar(self):
        print("grrr", self.name, " - esta ladrando...")


# Form 2
class Cat():

    def __init__(self, name):
        self.name = name

    def mauyar(self):
        print("miau miau", self.name, " - esta mauyando...")


# Form 3
class Rat(object):

    def __init__(self, name):
        self.name = name

    def molestar(self):
        print("ggg ggg", self.name, " - esta molestando...")


# Creating objets
primerPerro = Dog("rufo")
primerPerro.ladrar()

primerGato = Cat("gaturra")
primerGato.mauyar()

primerraton = Rat("micky")
primerraton.molestar()
```

Check this documentation about classes in the Python files ([LINK](https://docs.python.org/3.8/tutorial/classes.html)) and I can see that they use the first way to define the classes but *I couldn't find reference to the second and third way.*

**In which cases would the second and third form be used (they are correct forms)**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- In Python 3-only code, you'd just use the first form (because the other forms are needlessly verbose and change nothing about the behavior on Python 3).
- If you need to write code that still produces new-style classes when run on Python 2, you'd use the third form, and the other forms would produce old-style classes (which are generally inferior to new-style classes in the few cases where they differ). Given that Python 2 has reached end-of-life, I'd think twice before trying to write new code that supports it.
- The second form serves no purpose, and should be avoided as a case of unnecessary parentheses disease.

Answer (score 2):

This way, you define what classes your class inherits from:

```
class MyClass(SuperClass):
```

You can list multiple super classes, but even if you don't specify any, your class will always inherit from `object`, if you are in Python 3, so these are the same:

```
class MyClass(object):

class MyClass():

class MyClass:
```

However, in Python 2, classes did not inherit from object if you did not specify that, so there was a difference and most classes explicitly inherited from `object`.

See this for the explanation of what happens in Python 2:
[What is the difference between old style and new style classes in Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54867/what-is-the-difference-between-old-style-and-new-style-classes-in-python)